# Opengl 330 core creating and using a texture 2D

Tags: c, opengl, texture-mapping

It's been a while since I've wrote some graphics programming and I've been staring at this for quite some time now and can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

This is how I am creating my texture.

```
GLuint create_texture(const char* filename) {
    SDL_Surface* surface;
    GLenum tex_format;
    GLint num_colors;
    GLuint tex_id;
    char* file_path;

file_path = get_resource(filename);
surface = IMG_Load(file_path);
if (!surface) {
    SDL_Log("failed to create surface\n");
    SDL_Quit();
    return -1;
} else {
    if ((surface->w & (surface->w - 1)) != 0) {
        SDL_Log("image { %s } width is not power of 2\n", filename);
    }
    if ((surface->h & (surface->h - 1)) != 0) {
        SDL_Log("image { %s } height is not power of 2\n", filename);
    }

    num_colors = surface->format->BytesPerPixel;
    if (num_colors == 4) {
        if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
            tex_format = GL_RGBA;
        else
            tex_format = GL_BGRA;
    }
    if (num_colors == 3) {
        if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
            tex_format = GL_RGB;
        else
            tex_format = GL_BGR;

    } else {
        SDL_Log("pixel image format shouldn't get here! Quitting\n");
        SDL_Quit();
    };

    glGenTextures(1, &tex_id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_id);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, tex_format, surface->w, surface->h, 0,
                 tex_format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);
}
if (surface) SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
free(file_path);

return tex_id;
}
```

this code above works correctly for loading the image data.

vertex shader

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 a_pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 a_col;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 a_tex;

uniform mat4 u_mvp_mat;
uniform mat4 u_mod_mat;
uniform mat4 u_view_mat;
uniform mat4 u_proj_mat;

out vec4 f_color;
out vec2 f_tex;

void main()
{
    gl_Position =   u_mvp_mat * vec4(a_pos, 1.0);
    f_tex = a_tex;
    f_color = a_col;
}
```

fragment shader.

```
#version 330 core

in vec4 f_color;
out vec4 o_color;

in vec2 f_tex;
uniform sampler2D u_sprite_tex;

void main (void)
{
    o_color = f_color;
    o_color = texture(u_sprite_tex, f_tex);
}
```

this is how i setup my VBO

```
quad = ren2d_new(); //just a wrapper around a quad or two tri.
ren2d_set_tint(quad, 0, 1, 0, 1); //setting the color to green

pos_loc = get_attrib_location(ce_get_default_shader(), "a_pos");
col_loc = get_attrib_location(ce_get_default_shader(), "a_col");
mvp_matrix_loc = get_uniform_location(ce_get_default_shader(), "u_mvp_mat");
model_mat_loc = get_uniform_location(ce_get_default_shader(), "u_mod_mat");
view_mat_loc = get_uniform_location(ce_get_default_shader(), "u_view_mat");
proj_matrix_loc =
    get_uniform_location(ce_get_default_shader(), "u_proj_mat");

tex_loc = get_uniform_location(ce_get_default_shader(), "u_sprite_tex");

camera = cam_2d_new(ce_get_width(), ce_get_height());

model_mat = mat4_identity();
mat4_scale(model_mat, 128, 128, 1);

tex_id = create_texture("test.png");

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

glGenBuffers(1, &vert_buff);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vert_buff);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quad->vertices), quad->vertices,
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glGenBuffers(1, &col_buff);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, col_buff);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quad->colors), quad->colors,
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(quad->tex_coords),
                      quad->tex_coords);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glGenBuffers(1, &ind_buff);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ind_buff);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quad->indices), quad->indices,
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

this is my render function:

```
glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

//could my texturing problems be here?
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_id);
glUniform1i(tex_loc, 0);

glUseProgram(ce_get_default_shader()->shader_program);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

//excuse the silly names
ce_get_view_matrices(&vview_mat, &pproj_mat, &mmvp_mat);

mat4_multi(&mmvp_mat, &vview_mat, model_mat);
mat4_multi(&mmvp_mat, &pproj_mat, &mmvp_mat);
glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp_matrix_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, mat4_get_data(&mmvp_mat));

glUniformMatrix4fv(model_mat_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, mat4_get_data(model_mat));
glUniformMatrix4fv(view_mat_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, mat4_get_data(&vview_mat));
glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_matrix_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, mat4_get_data(&pproj_mat));

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, quad->vertex_count, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

I am just getting a black quad. I can't track it down and i've been staring at this for quite a few hours now.

doing some very basic testing in the fragment shader like this.

```
#version 330 core

in vec4 f_color;
out vec4 o_color;

in vec2 f_tex;
uniform sampler2D u_sprite_tex;

void main (void)
{
    //o_color = f_color;
    vec4 c;
    if(f_tex.y == 1.0) { c = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); }
    if(f_tex.y == 0.0) { c = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0); }
    o_color = c;
    o_color = texture(u_sprite_tex, f_tex);
}
```

my quads turn out to be blue both along the x and the y axis. That seems to be that the only value being passed in in 0.0 which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

okay this was definitely a problem of my own creation. The reason that I was getting segmentation fault was because of this code.

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

glGenBuffers(1, &vert_buff);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vert_buff);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quad->vertices), quad->vertices,
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glGenBuffers(1, &col_buff);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, col_buff);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quad->colors), quad->colors,
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); //right here

glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(quad->tex_coords),
                      quad->tex_coords);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);


glGenBuffers(1, &ind_buff);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ind_buff);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quad->indices), quad->indices,
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

after you bind your vbo buffer to zero attempting to access it will cause a segmentation fault...

After that just making sure that I sent the proper data to the gpu and all other code worked as expected.

```
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glGenBuffers(1, &col_buff);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, col_buff);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quad->colors), quad->colors,
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
//glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); //right here remove this

//properly setup the local data to gpu data
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, rend2d_get_sizeof_tex_coord(quad),
             rend2d_get_tex_coord_data(quad), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); //put it here after finished with vbo
```

after those two changes everything worked as expected. Hopefully this can save someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two things that might be wrong:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(quad->tex_coords),
                  quad->tex_coords);
```

Are you sure that `quad->tex_coords` contains 4-dimensional vectors? The fragment shader expects `vec2`. If you only supply two floats per vertex, you have to change the second parameter to two. When OpenGL tries to read from a too small `ARRAY_BUFFER` this can also cause segmentation faults. Note, that attributes are set to inactive if they do not contribute to the final color, thus the texture coordinates might only be read when textures are used.

Second: You are calling `glGenerateMipmap` before uploading data to the texture.